# Como fazer ordenação por dois parâmetros com Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, order-by

Estou fazendo uma ordenação decrescente para listar ganhadores, porém ela é baseada por nota.

*Minha busca é a seguinte:*

```
public function getHistorico($id_avaliacao)
{
    return $this->where('avaliacao_id', $id_avaliacao)
        ->orderBy('nota', 'desc')
        ->get();
}
```

Gostaria de fazer com que se a nota de dois colaboradores forem iguais, o colaborador com `data_admissao` menor seja listado antes, tem como fazer isso usando o *eloquent*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
$this->where('avaliacao_id', $id_avaliacao)
     ->orderBy('nota', 'desc')
     ->orderBy('data_admissao', 'asc')
     ->get();
```

Podes invocar `orderBy` as vezes que quiseres

Comment: Show, funcionou assim que o sistema liberar aceito sua resposta =D